# C++ Use object from main.cpp's file

Tags: c++, object

I have a program (matrix.hpp, matrix.cpp, main.cpp) and the class Matrix_t. In main.cpp i create a object 'A' with the constructor's class, and i have a function in matrix.cpp:

```
it_t Matrix_t::element(ix_t i,ix_t j,Matrix_t& SM){
   if ((i<1)||(i>m_)||(j<1)||(j>n_)){
  cerr << "Error" << endl;
  return 0;    }
   int pos = (i-1)*SM.n_+j-1;
   return SM.base_[pos]; }
```

If i create a new object 'B' but in matrix.cpp, i can call the previous function of this way: element(1,1,B). But if i pass the object 'A' created in main.cpp? If i code: `element(1,1,A)` i get a error (A didn't declared, logic).

What's the form to call `element()` with 'A' object?

PD: this is the main.cpp

```
 int main(int argc,char** argv) 
 {   Matrix_t A;

 A.read(cin);   
     A.write(cout);

 const double det=A.determinant();  
     cout << "Determinant: " << det <<
                        "\n" << endl;

    return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: My eyes are bleeding at the indentation. Please fix it if you want others to read your code and help you.

Comment: you could call `A.element(1, 1, A)`. element is not a static function and thus needs a 'this' argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Matrix_t::element` on `A` within the scope, where `A` is visible. So in the main function

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "matrix.hpp"

 using namespace std;

 int main(int argc,char** argv) 
 {
     Matrix_t A;

     A.read(cin);   
     A.write(cout);

     const double det=A.determinant();  
     cout << "Determinant: " << det << "\n" << endl;


    //-----------
    auto z = A.element(1,1,B);
    // or if you wish, B.element(1,1,A)
    //-----------

    return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: But i need call the element()'s function in the matrix.cpp and don't in the main.cpp.

Comment: Are you sure `A` should be in main? What is the use case, is there one `A` for every instance, or a shared one for all of them? Or can there be many `A`s for a single instance?

Comment: Yes i do. 'A' is the only instance, but don't worry if isn't possible do i want.

Comment: You could add `extern Matrix_t A;` in matrix_t.hpp and move the definition from the main function to the global scope of matrix_t.cpp.